# Having to click tab bar item two times to change view controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

When I build even the most basic default Tabbed Bar application in swift I have to click two times on the tab bar icon to change to the next view. How do I change this to only be a single click? It wasn't always this way, but now when I create any sort of tab bar controller it behaves like this.

Comment: if you create a new single view app and just drag and drop the TabBarController from Object library onto your storyboard and make it the initial viewController, you will be able to see that tab switches in just one click. Can you please share some more detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: just override setter of `var selectedIndex: Int` property